# Switching between apps with open keyboard will trigger error message and result in empty UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikeyboard

I am fighting with a weird problem on iOS (12.x):
When switching to my app from an application which has the keyboard open (e.g. iMessage), will result in a log message:

> ... [Accessibility] Got a keyboard will hide notification, but keyboard was not even present.
>
> ... [Accessibility] Got a keyboard did hide notification, but keyboard was not even present.

Also if I switch from my app to an app with open keyboard, it shows:

> ... [Accessibility] Got a keyboard will show notification, but keyboard was not on screen.

In addition my UICollectionView, which is located at the bottom of my app is empty, when coming from an app with keyboard open:

> collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems is empty

while it would have visible items if there is no keyboard shown.

Investigating into the view hierarchy only reveals that in one case there are not cells while in the other case the UICollectionView has cells.

Is there a way to fix this? It seems like a kind of odd problem.

Here is the stack trace for the keyboard will hide notification, which appears once I switch from an app with keyboard shown to my app.

```
#0  0x0000000100b791d0 in CycleViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:) at  ...
#1  0x0000000100b79668 in @objc CycleViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:) ()
#2  0x00000001e3aa4618 in __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#3  0x00000001e2f7419c in __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ ()
#4  0x00000001e2f7415c in ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke ()
#5  0x00000001e2f73604 in _CFXRegistrationPost ()
#6  0x00000001e2f73290 in ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke ()
#7  0x00000001e2ee8cb4 in -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] ()
#8  0x00000001e2f72d14 in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#9  0x00000001e3991b24 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#10 0x0000000210ab952c in -[UIInputWindowController postStartNotifications:withInfo:] ()
#11 0x0000000210abc3c8 in __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke.1073 ()
#12 0x000000021118051c in +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] ()
#13 0x00000002111809f8 in +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:start:completion:] ()
#14 0x0000000210abbcb4 in -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] ()
#15 0x0000000210ac3cc8 in -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] ()
#16 0x0000000210abb200 in -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] ()
#17 0x0000000210b3fff4 in -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] ()
#18 0x0000000210b38f44 in -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] ()
#19 0x0000000210b550f4 in -[_UIRemoteKeyboards keyboardChanged:shouldConsiderSnapshottingKeyboard:isLocalEvent:] ()
#20 0x0000000210b553d8 in __55-[_UIRemoteKeyboards queue_keyboardChanged:onComplete:]_block_invoke ()
#21 0x00000001055f81c0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#22 0x00000001055fbd44 in _dispatch_block_invoke_direct ()
#23 0x00000001e5ad1b08 in __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#24 0x00000001e5ad1774 in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] ()
#25 0x00000001e5ad1de0 in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] ()
#26 0x00000001e2f966c4 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#27 0x00000001e2f96640 in __CFRunLoopDoSource0 ()
#28 0x00000001e2f95ef8 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#29 0x00000001e2f90bd8 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#30 0x00000001e2f904b8 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#31 0x00000001e5243be8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#32 0x0000000210cc41b8 in UIApplicationMain ()
#33 0x0000000100b7209c in main at ...
```

Update 1:

Actually @Digitalsa1nt gave me a good hint for a workaround. If I catch the keyboard did hide notification and reload the collectionView it will reload the items. Now I'm only left with a short flicker, which isn't nice, but serves as a workaround for now.

Comment: crashed your app?? insane...

Comment: no, it didn't crash, but as described parts of the UI are empty.

Comment: At which point in the UI life-cycle are you receiving/sending keyboard notifications?

Comment: That was a first world problem

Comment: Added a stack trace of the notification coming in. At this stage the collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems is empty.